# com.android.Volley.ServerError - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500

Tags: php, android, android-volley

The error is just like the title, and from various posts in SO mentioned about server side of error.

I just repeat the same PHP script with differences in table name and column name. The script is for update column, but only one of the columns not updated - `bizPhone`, and deleted the content. Other column - `bizName`, `bizAddress` etc, no problem.

I have compared the string in Config file and in PHP script - no difference.

Original PHP script:

```
$sql = "SELECT countryID FROM wg_countries WHERE country = '$country'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $result = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $countryID = $row[0];
        }

        $sql2 = "SELECT categoryID FROM wg_categories WHERE category = '$category'";
        $res2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        $result2 = array();
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
            $categoryID = $row2[0];
        }

        $sql3 = "UPDATE wg_groups SET groupName = '$groupName', description = '$description', countryID = '$countryID', categoryID = '$categoryID', url = '$url' WHERE groupID = '$groupID'";


        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql3)){
            echo "Successfully Updated";
        }else{
            echo "Could not update";
        }
```

Copied and modified PHP script:

```
$sql = "SELECT countryID FROM wg_countries WHERE country = '$country'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $result = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $countryID = $row[0];
        }

        $sql2 = "SELECT categoryID FROM wg_categories WHERE category = '$category'";
        $res2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        $result2 = array();
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
            $categoryID = $row2[0];
        }

        $sql3 = "UPDATE wg_biz SET bizName = '$bizName', bizAddress = '$bizAddress', countryID = '$countryID', categoryID = '$categoryID', bizURL = '$bizURL', bizPhone = '$bizPhone' WHERE bizID = '$bizID'";


        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql3)){
            echo "Successfully Updated";
        }else{
            echo "Could not update";
        }
```

Since I keep getting error 500, I have checked the log errors in GoDaddy but no details - just 500 xx xx xx something like that.

Also, the query already tested and have no problem. Where should I check again? :(

Answer (score 0):

500 error is a server error. not android error. you can look in apache error log to see the error.

if you call that script from the browser do you get the same error?

the debugging is step by step.

1. call with Volley any URL or empty file and print it. see that you don't get an error (see if it is working then you know Volley is working)
2. then use Volley to print the input with like a PHP script like: var_dump($_REQUEST);
3. if your script is failing and not volley, then print the result of each step in the PHP file. maybe print something and exit after the first part. to see if the script comes to this point. also, you can print the SQL statements and try to run them by hand to see if they are working.

Comment: since I use POST, is it okay to change to GET for debugging purpose?

Comment: yes, I have edited answer to explain better the debugging steps.